# How to allow only few subnets for Hyper-V VM?

Tags: hyper-v

There 10-15 Hyper-V VMs on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter server.

I need to block all Internet access for one VM on vSwitch and allow only few subnets.

For example, first 2 VMs has access only to xx.xx.xx.xx/22 and yy.yy.yy.yy/22 and other VM's have full access to Internet.

How can I implement this? I'm ready to use other software to realize it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do that is with controlled VLAN membership. That way you can separate things like storage networks from general access networks. This way you also don't merge a bunch of subnets on the same broadcast domain, which is typically pretty undesirable (for the reasons you've posed above - no isolation).